# how to set value list item in adapter class and get value on Button click in android

Tags: android

Adapter Class:

```
public List<TSPDataModel> employeeData;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    RadioGroup radiogroupbutton;
    String[] data = {"Document not clear","Adress is not Visibile","Photo is not pasted","Signature is not Avilable"};
    String   value;
    public TSPListDocumentadapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<TSPDataModel> objects)

    {
        this.employeeData = objects;
        this.mContext = context;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tspdocumentlistitem, null);
            holder.relatvie1=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.relatvie1);
            holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.accecpt = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
            holder.reject = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
            holder.statustextview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.statustextview);
            holder.poaedittext=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.poieditext);
           holder.poaedittext=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.poaedittext);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtName.setText(employeeData.get(position).getName());
        holder.poaedittext.setText(employeeData.get(position).getPoa());

        holder.accecpt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.statustextview.setText("Accepted");

                employeeData.get(position).setSelected(true);
                employeeData.get(position).getOrderId();
                holder.relatvie1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.acceptedcolor);

            }
        });

        holder.reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showdilog();
                holder.statustextview.setText("Rejected");
                employeeData.get(position).setSelected(false);
                employeeData.get(position).setReasone(value);
                holder.relatvie1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rejectcolor);
            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtName;
        ImageView reject;
        ImageView accecpt;
        TextView statustextview;
        TextView poiedittext;
        TextView poaedittext;
        RelativeLayout relatvie1;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return employeeData.size();
    }

    public TSPDataModel getItem(int position) {
        return employeeData.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    public void showdilog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layoutpopup);
        radiogroupbutton = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_gp_day);
        ListView listview = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_slot_list);
        Button setbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setbutton);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> myadpter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, data);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            list.add(data[i]);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(myadpter);
        listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                value = data[position];
                Toast.makeText(mContext, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        setbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();


            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

This Button click in my actvity class :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            try {

                List<TSPDataModel> empData = adapter.employeeData;
                System.out.println("Total Size :" + empData.size());

                for (TSPDataModel employeeModel : empData) {
                    if (employeeModel.isSelected()) {
              Toast.makeText(TSPDocumentListActvity.this, employeeModel.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

String Reasonse=   employeeModel.getresonse() ;                

                        Toast.makeText(TSPDocumentListActvity.this, "false" + employeeModel.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

First i Print data in Listview then each list view  item there is accept and reject Button is there when we click  on accept then no   alert will asked only reject button reason will ask which is come on listitem on popup i want to get that selected reason on Button click in actvity but i always get null value please help me where i am doing wrong

Comment: please include the logcat error

Comment: You need to write the accept or reject logic inside `showdilog()` method.

Comment: can u please tell me how to wrong Accept and reject Logic inside show dilog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your reject button and showDialog code to

```
holder.reject.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showdilog(position);
                holder.statustextview.setText("Rejected");
                holder.relatvie1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.rejectcolor);
            }
        });
```

and showDualog to

```
public void showdilog(int list_position) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layoutpopup);
        radiogroupbutton = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_gp_day);
        ListView listview = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_slot_list);
        Button setbutton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setbutton);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayAdapter<String> myadpter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, data);
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            list.add(data[i]);
        }
        listview.setAdapter(myadpter);
        listview.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                value = data[position];
                employeeData.get(list_position).setSelected(false);
                employeeData.get(list_position).setReasone(value);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        setbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();


            }
        });

        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: OK wait elt me try Your Logic

Comment: @H Raval still null value coming